# How to use coercion with sig in coq

Tags: coq, coercion

I have a code like

```
Definition even := {n : nat | exists k, n = k + k}.

Definition even_to_nat (e : even) : nat.
Admitted.

Coercion even_to_nat : even >-> nat.

Example Ex : forall n : even, exists k, k + k = n.
Admitted.

Example Ex2 : forall k, exists n : even, k + k = n.
Admitted.
```

How should I remove `Admitted` in this case?

Also, why does

```
Example Ex' : forall n : even, exists k, n = k + k
```

not work even with coercion? Is there a nice way to remove such errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a definition for the `even_to_nat` function written in Gallina:

```
Definition even := {n : nat | exists k, n = k + k}.

Definition even_to_nat (e : even) : nat :=
  match e with
  | exist _ n _ => n
  end.

Coercion even_to_nat : even >-> nat.
```

It pattern matches on `e` to retrieve the wrapped natural number `n`.

This is an equivalent implementation using tactics:

```
Definition even_to_nat_tac (e : even) : nat.
destruct e.
auto.
Defined.
```

The `destruct` tactic essentially pattern matches on `e`. Then, `auto` automatically uses the natural number inside to finish the definition.

Here is a Gallina implementation of your first example:

```
Example Ex : forall n : even, exists k, k + k = n :=
  fun n => match n with
  | exist _ n (ex_intro _ k eq) => ex_intro (fun k => k + k = n) k (eq_sym eq)
  end.
```

Essentially, it pattern matches on `n`, retrieves the `k` and the proof that `n = k + k`, then uses `eq_sym` to flip the equality.

Here is an implementation for `Ex2`:

```
Example Ex2 : forall k, exists n : even, k + k = n :=
  fun k =>
  let n := k + k in
  let exists_k := ex_intro (fun k => n = k + k) k eq_refl in
  let even_nat := exist (fun n => exists k, n = k + k) n exists_k in
  ex_intro (fun n => k + k = even_to_nat n) even_nat eq_refl.
```

`exists_k` is the proof contained inside an even number stating `exists k, n + n = k`. `even_nat` is an even number fulfilling the condition `exists n, k + k = n`, where `n` is obviously `k + k`. Finally, I inhabit the desired type. It seems that I can't use coercions here, so I explicitly use `even_to_nat`.

Alternatively, the coercion works if I add a type annotation:

```
Example Ex2 : forall k, exists n : even, k + k = n :=
  fun k =>
  let n := k + k in
  let exists_k := ex_intro (fun k => n = k + k) k eq_refl in
  let even_nat := exist (fun n => exists k, n = k + k) n exists_k in
  ex_intro (fun (n : even) => k + k = n) even_nat eq_refl.
```

For your `Ex'` example, see the warning in [this example from the coercion documentation](https://coq.github.io/doc/V8.10.1/refman/addendum/implicit-coercions.html?highlight=coercion#coercion-at-function-application). Given the coercion `Coercion bool_in_nat : bool >-> nat.`:

> Note that Check (true = O) would fail. This is "normal" behavior of coercions. To validate true=O, the coercion is searched from nat to bool. There is none.

You can only coerce on the right side of the equality type, not the left.

Comment: I have a question : Is there a way to prove `Ex2` with tactics?